# Text document is becoming file folder

Tags: java, file

Here is my class, what I am doing wrong. Why is my text document becoming a file folder. Please explain what is going on and how I can correct it. Thank you

```
public class InputOutput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("C:/Users/CrypticDev/Desktop/File/Text.txt");
        Scanner input = null;


        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
                pw.println("Some data that we have stored");
                pw.println("Another data that we stored");

                pw.close();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Error " + e.toString());
            }
        } else {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            input = new Scanner(file);

            while(input.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(input.nextLine());
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                input.close();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(file.exists());
        System.out.println(file.length());
        System.out.println(file.canRead());
        System.out.println(file.canWrite());
        System.out.println(file.isFile());
        System.out.println(file.isDirectory());
    }
}
```

Thanks. The above is my Java class.

Comment: This is not what im asking... I need to know why its creating a file folder instead of creating a text document..

Answer (score 4):

You mistakingly assume `Text.txt` is not a directory name.

`mkdirs()` creates a directory (and all directories needed to create it). In your case 'Text.txt'

See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs().

It is perfectly fine for a directory to have a . in it.

You could use `getParentFile()` to get the directory you want to create and use `mkdirs()` on that.

Comment: The fact that it ends up as a directory is caused by `mkdirs()`. `new File()` never creates files or directories, just an instance.

Answer (score 1):

For additional informations. Here is the différence between the two representaions of files and directories:

```
final File file1 = new File("H:/Test/Text.txt"); // Creates NO File/Directory
file1.mkdirs(); // Creates directory named "Text.txt" and its parent directory "H:/Test" if it doesn't exist (may fail regarding to permissions on folders).

final File file = new File("H:/Test2/Text.txt"); // Creates NO File/Directory
try {
    file.createNewFile(); // Creates file named "Text.txt" (if doesn't exist) in the folder "H:/Test2". If parents don't exist, no file is created.
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code:

```
else {
        file.mkdirs();
     }
```

with:

```
else {
        if (!file.isFile()&&file.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please also explain WHY this works and what was going on. Just pasting code that fixes the problem does only partly help.

Comment: It is easy to understand, mkdir method creates a directory with the file object name, so it is creating a directory with name Test.txt.

Comment: In my code, first it check if the file object has a actual file in directory, this part of code is to understand if the file object specified is a directory path or a path to actual existing file.Once that condition is satisfied other one is to create a directory from the given path. and finally inside if condition the file.

Comment: Let me know, how it goes.